# SQL Query - Determining new visitors each day

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a schema which looks as follows (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   DateTimeOffset HitDate NOT NULL,
   IpAddress varchar(15)
)
```

A sample row might look as follows:

`'7/10/2013 8:05:29 -07:00' '111.222.333.444'`

I'm trying to work out a query that will give me, for each day (e.g., 7/10/2013) the number of unique IpAddresses. Actually, that part is fairly easy and I already created a query for that. However, for this query what I want is the number of unique `IpAddresses` that had never existed before the current date. I don't care about after the date, just before the date.

For example, assume I have the following data and this is all I have:

```
'7/10/2013 8:05:29 -07:00' '111.222.333.444'
'7/10/2013 12:05:29 -07:00' '111.222.333.222'
'7/9/2013 9:05:29 -07:00' '111.222.333.444'
'7/9/2013 10:05:29 -07:00' '111.222.333.555'
'7/8/2013 11:05:29 -07:00' '111.222.333.222'
'7/8/2013 4:05:29 -07:00' '111.222.333.555'
```

The query should output the following:

```
'7/8/2013' 2 (neither IpAddress existed before this date so both are new)
'7/9/2013' 1 (only one of the IpAddresses is new - the one ending in '444')
'7/10/2013' 0 (both IpAddresses had existed before this date)
```

Target database is `SQL Server 2012`. I'm offering a bounty of 100 points to the first person to correctly create a SQL statement.

Comment: It's a timezone offset.

Comment: We store all our data with timezone offset information

Comment: HitDate is not an existing type

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - It certainly is.

Comment: @RandyMinder I can't find any documentation and when i declare a variable of the type HitDate, I get an error: declare @a HitDate

Comment: I think an error has crept in; I believe the second line should read `HitDate DateTimeOffset NOT NULL`, and have written my solution based upon this assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (in my opinion) is to find the earliest date when an IP address appeared, and then use that for aggregation:

```
select cast(minHitDate as Date), count(*) as FirstTimeVisitors
from (select IpAddress, min(HitDate) as minHitDate
      from MyTable t
      group by IpAddress
     ) i
group by cast(minHitDate as Date)
order by 1;
```

An alternative form which lets you count 1st time visitors, 2nd time visitors, and so on uses `dense_rank()`:

```
select cast(HitDate as Date),
       count(distinct IpAddress) as NumVisitors,
       sum(case when nth = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as FirstTime,
       sum(case when nth = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as SecondTime,
       sum(case when nth = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as ThirdTime
from (select IpAddress,
             dense_rank() over (partition by IpAddress
                                order by cast(HitDate as date)
                               ) as nth
      from MyTable t
     ) i
group by cast(HitDate as Date)
order by 1;
```

Comment: Very nice idea about determining the earliest (or first) date and IP address appeared and then going from there. I actually implemented that solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (
HitDate DateTimeOffset NOT NULL,
IpAddress varchar(15))

insert #mytable values
('7/10/2013 8:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.444'),
('7/10/2013 12:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.222'),
('7/9/2013 9:05:29 -07:00' ,'111.222.333.444'),
('7/9/2013 10:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.555'),
('7/8/2013 11:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.222'),
('7/8/2013 4:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.555')

;WITH a AS
(
 select 
 cast(HitDate as date) HitDate,  
 IpAddress
 from #mytable
), b AS
(
 SELECT  min(HitDate) md, IpAddress
 FROM a
 GROUP BY IpAddress
)
SELECT c.HitDate, Count(distinct b.IpAddress) IpAddress
FROM b
right join (select distinct HitDate from a) c
on b.md = c.HitDate
GROUP by c.HitDate
```

Result:

```
HitDate    IpAddress
2013-07-08 2
2013-07-09 1
2013-07-10 0
```

Comment: Nice - this produces correct results. I'll give you and Hiren the 100 rep points, if I can.

Comment: @Hosea146 I don't think you can control that. I believe when you put up a reward, the people with the most votes gets the reward.

Comment: @Hosea146 found a way to improve my script

Answer (score 2):

Try Following Query :

```
SELECT A.HITDATE , ISNULL(B.CNT , 0) AS COUNT
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE , HITDATE) AS HITDATE
FROM mytable1
) AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT CONVERT(DATE , HITDATE) AS HITDATE , COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM MyTable1 AS A
WHERE IpAddress NOT IN 
(
SELECT B.IpAddress FROM mytable1 AS B WHERE A.HITDATE > B.HITDATE
)
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE , HITDATE)
) AS B ON A.HITDATE = B.HITDATE
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7536a/1

Comment: Nice - this produces correct results. And SQLFiddle is nice too. Never seen that before.

Comment: @Hosea146 This will not produce the right result if there are identical rows

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
DT datetime NOT NULL,
IP varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT '2013-07-10', 'aaa' UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-07-10', 'bbb' UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-07-10', 'ccc' UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-07-09', 'aaa' UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-07-09', 'bbb' UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-07-08', 'aaa' UNION ALL
SELECT '2013-07-08', 'bbb'


SELECT CAST(T1.DT AS DATE) Date, COUNT(T1.IP) 
FROM Test T1
WHERE T1.IP NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT T2.IP FROM Test T2 WHERE CAST(T2.DT AS DATE) < T1.DT
)
GROUP BY CAST(T1.DT AS DATE)
```

which correctly results as:

```
Date:       Unique IPs
2013-07-08  2
2013-07-10  1
```

Comment: missing a date '2013-07-09' which is the hard part of this question

Answer (score 1):

[Edit - altered to use a DateTimeOffset instead]

I've come up with the following, starting off with creating the base MyTable:

```
-- Test data creation to match schema & examples

create TABLE MyTable (
   HitDate DateTimeOffset  NOT NULL,
   IpAddress varchar(15)
)

insert into MyTable values ('7/10/2013 8:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.444')
insert into MyTable values ('7/10/2013 12:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.222')
insert into MyTable values ('7/9/2013 9:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.444')
insert into MyTable values ('7/9/2013 10:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.555')
insert into MyTable values ('7/8/2013 11:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.222')
insert into MyTable values ('7/8/2013 4:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.555')

-- actual solution starts here

create TABLE #MyTable (
   HitDate date,
   IpAddress varchar(15)
)

-- populate data into required format for main query

insert into #MyTable SELECT HitDate, IpAddress FROM MyTable

-- main query

select distinct convert(varchar(10), HitDate, 101) HitDate, ISNULL(dateCounts.counter, 0) NewIPAddresses
from #MyTable mainDates
left outer join 
    (
        select main.HitDate dateValue, count(*) counter from
            #MyTable main
            left outer join #MyTable sub on main.IpAddress = sub.IpAddress and main.HitDate > sub.HitDate
            where sub.IpAddress is null
            group by main.HitDate
    ) dateCounts on dateCounts.dateValue = HitDate
```

which gives:

```
    HitDate        NewIPAddresses 
    -------------- --------------
    07/08/2013     2
    07/09/2013     1
    07/10/2013     0
```

Comment: This is not right. The data type in your table is wrong. It should be DateTimeOffset, not Date. The results are not correct.

Comment: @RandyMinder Are you connected to the original questioner? If so, maybe some additional test data would be of use, as the above works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATE,T1.[HitDate]) AS [HitDate]
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN T2.[IpAddress] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IpAddress
FROM 
    YourTableName T1 
LEFT JOIN
    YourTableName T2 ON T1.IpAddress = T2.IpAddress
AND 
    T1.[HitDate] > T2.[HitDate]
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,T1.[HitDate])
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95778/1)

[**data.stackexchange demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/124416)

**OUTPUT**

```
HitDate    IpAddress
2013-07-08  2
2013-07-09  1
2013-07-10  0
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks right too but is a little less complex...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(IPAddress)
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE , HITDATE) <= '2013-07-09'
GROUP BY IPAddress
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(CONVERT(DATE , HITDATE)) = '2013-07-09';
```

Comment: This is not going to work. I cannot hard code a date in the query. The data I showed in my post was just sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I used a cursor in T-SQL to achieve the desired result.

Code below:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(HitDate, IpAddress) values ('7/10/2013 8:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.444')
INSERT INTO MyTable(HitDate, IpAddress) VALUES('7/10/2013 12:05:29 -07:00',     '111.222.333.222')
INSERT INTO MyTable(HitDate, IpAddress) VALUES('7/9/2013 9:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.444')
INSERT INTO MyTable(HitDate, IpAddress) VALUES('7/9/2013 10:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.555')
INSERT INTO MyTable(HitDate, IpAddress) VALUES('7/8/2013 11:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.222')
INSERT INTO MyTable(HitDate, IpAddress) VALUES('7/8/2013 4:05:29 -07:00', '111.222.333.555')


DECLARE @HitDate DATE

DECLARE cCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL
FOR
SELECT 
    DISTINCT CAST(HitDate AS DATE)
FROM 
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    CAST(HitDate AS DATE) ASC

OPEN cCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @HitDate
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT @HitDate, COUNT(IpAddress)
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE IpAddress NOT IN (SELECT IpAddress FROM MyTable WHERE HitDate < @HitDate) AND     CAST(HitDate AS DATE) = @HitDate

    FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @HitDate
END

CLOSE cCursor
DEALLOCATE cCursor
```

The output is as follows:

2013-07-08  2 
2013-07-09  1 
2013-07-10  0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, mt.HitDate) AS hitDate
           , COUNT(firstDate.ipAddress) AS newIPAddresses
      FROM MyTable mt
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT IpAddress, MIN(HitDate) AS FirstHitDate
              FROM MyTable
          GROUP BY IpAddress) firstDate
          ON mt.HitDate = firstDate.FirstHitDate
          AND mt.IpAddress = firstDate.IpAddress
  GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, mt.HitDate)
  ORDER BY 1
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
hitDate     newIPAddress
2013-07-08  2
2013-07-09  1
2013-07-10  0
```